# Difference between tree package and manual computation

Tags: r, cart

I have a simple example (only one independent variable)
to do the regression tree using the `tree` package in R, 
which reads

```
x = 1:10
y = c(5.56, 5.70, 5.91, 6.40, 6.80, 7.05, 8.90, 8.70, 9.00, 9.05)
library(tree)
sim.tree = tree(y~., data=data.frame(x=x,y=y))
sim.tree
```

And the result is shown as

```
1) root 10 19.110 7.307
  2) x < 5.5 5  1.064 6.074 *
  3) x > 5.5 5  2.847 8.540 *
```

Thus, we find that R gives the best  cutpoint $s=5.5$.
However, we compute the results by *recursive binary splitting* 
from the book ISLR [http://www-bcf.usc.edu/~gareth/ISL/]
to get

```
s   1.5     2.5     3.5     4.5     5.5     6.5     7.5     8.5     9.5  
c1  5.56    5.63    5.72    5.89    6.07    6.24    6.62    6.88    7.11 
c2  7.5     7.73    7.99    8.25    8.54    8.91    8.92    9.03    9.05 
m   15.72   12.07   8.36    5.78    3.91    1.93    8.01    11.73   15.74
```

where $s$ are the cutpoints, and

$$
R_1(j,s) = \{x|x^{(j)} \le s\},\quad R_2(j,s) = \{x|x^{(j)} \ge s\},\\
\min_{j, s} \left[ \min_{c_1} \sum_{x_i \in R_1(j, s)} (y_i -c_1)^2 
+ \min_{c_2} \sum_{x_i \in R_2(j, s)} (y_i -c_2)^2 \right ]
$$

(Note: $j=1$ since there is only one one independent variable)

We get that $s=6.5$ is the best, which is different from the **tree** package.
Any help? Besides, the **tree** package only gives depth=1 regression tree, how about depth>=2?